# Converting char array to ints

Tags: c

I know this is probably a very beginner question but I have been beating my head against it for a few hours. Any tips would be appreciated it.

I am given a null terminated string. I am attempting to use C and strtol to convert it to ints, which works great until the last character before the NULL which is a /n. I am not sure how to get strtol to stop before that character.

Conversion code:

```
char *end;
arr[0] = strtol(temps, &end, 10);
for(int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++){
    arr[i] = strtol(end, &end, 10);
}
arr[n] = strtol(end, NULL, 10);
```

Input:

```
49 32 45 50 32 45 56 32 52 32 53 10 // ascii values
```

Expected Output:

```
1 -2 -8 4 5 // character array
```

Output:

```
1 -2 -8 4 1 // int array
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Explain what do you think is wrong with your program. Include sample incorrect output in the program. Explain how it was obtained (your code fragment does not have any I/O functions.) **NB**: Are you sure you want to pass `end` as the first parameter to `strtol`?

Comment: Hi, sorry, the int array output is the incorrect output. It should be outputting a 5 but it is outputting a 1.
I think maybe I am not understanding the str_end argument well enough to make it understand that it should stop at \n. I believe the first end is correct. I just think the last NULL is incorrect.
For I/O, it is giving me the character array temps[] designated by the ascii values output (I did not include the NULL termination but it is there). I need to convert it to a int array,

Comment: Post the definition of `arr[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line probably writes out of array bounds:

```
arr[n] = strtol(end, NULL, 10);
```

In any case, this should be `arr[n-1]`, since the last index assigned to was `n-2`. But the logic can be simplified, making the code less susceptible to such errors:

```
char *end;
arr[0] = strtol(temps, &end, 10);
for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
    arr[i] = strtol(end, &end, 10);
}
```

Or yet further simplified to:

```
char *end = temps;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    arr[i] = strtol(end, &end, 10);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I feel silly. Does strtol include \n by default as one of it's end characters?

Comment: @MushinZero-- not exactly; [`strtol()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.1.4p2) essentially skips over leading whitespace characters, and attempts to convert up to the first non-numeric character, dependent upon the specified base.

Comment: @MushinZero-- it would have been more accurate for me to have said that `strtol()` attempts to convert up to the first character that is not recognized as being part of a number. Of course, `-` and  `+` may or may not be part of a number; also `x` or `X` may be part of a hex number. `strtol()` can handle these situations. If the base is specified as `0`, `strtol()` will attempt to interpret the string as an integer constant, i.e., decimal, octal (0nnn...), or hex (0xnnn..., or 0Xnnn...).